# Recursive function in Python that returns the number of even digits in an integer is not working

Tags: python, function, recursion, integer

I’m trying to create a recursive function that counts the even digits of a number.

It returns the value 1 every single time and I don’t know why. I’ve treated all the possible scenarios. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
def evendigits(n):
    if(n<10):
        if n%2 == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if n%2 == 0 :
        return (1 + evendigits(n/10))
    if n%2 != 0 :
        return evendigits(n/10)
```

Comment: Yelling "NOT WORKING" is not helpful. Instead, explain *what you think the issue is* in technical terms.

Comment: Sidetrack nitpick - given the `return` statements earlier, the last return doesn't need any condition checking. If you want one, it should be `else` rather than repeating the same arithmetic calculation you did in the prior `if`.

Comment: This is probably just an exercise, but worth mentioning, recursion overcomplicates the problem and isn't necessary. I'd use `def count_even_digits(n): return sum([1 for x in str(n) if int(x) % 2 == 0])` or write a loop if you want to use division.

Comment: Could be as short as : `return sum(map(str(n).count,"02468"))`

Comment: or `return (n+1)%2 + (0 if n<10 else count_even_digits(n//10))`

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using Python 3.

In Python 3, integer division is `//` not `/`

This code works correctly on my Python 3 installation.

```py
def evendigits(n):
    if(n<10):
        if n%2 == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if n%2 == 0 :
        return (1 + evendigits(n//10))
    if n%2 != 0 :
        return evendigits(n//10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are producing a float with `n/10` which is almost never going to be equal to an integer. You want integer division `n//10` with two slashes.

You should be able to figure this out yourself by adding `print` statements where you can get Python to show you the values as it recurses.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using integer division in your recursive calls, which causes the function to always `return 1`. When you perform `n/10` in Python, it performs integer division by default, discarding the fractional part.

To fix this issue, you should use the modulo operator `(%)` to extract the last digit, and then use integer division `(//)` to remove the last digit.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
def evendigits(n):
    if n < 10:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    last_digit = n % 10
    if last_digit % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + evendigits(n // 10)
    else:
        return evendigits(n // 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using this code. It is very simple.

```py
def count_even_digits(number):
    even_digits = []
    for digit in str(number):
        if int(digit) % 2 == 0:
            even_digits.append(digit)
    return len(even_digits)
```

This code you provided defines a function that counts the number of even digits in a given number. It first converts the number to a string and then iterates through each digit in the string. For each digit, if it is even, it adds it to a list, and at the end, it returns the total number of even digits found in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by iterating over digits in number and increment `count` if the digit is even:

```
n = 124
count = 0
while n > 0:
    digit = n % 10
    count += (digit % 2) == 0
    n //= 10
print(count) #2
```